# Inconsistent pvalues and confidence intervals

Tags: r, glm

Have been trying to fit a multiple logistic regression model in a given dataset but I seem to find *'strange results'* with some variables. The p-values and the confidence intervals seem not to be consistent. However, when I tried fitting the exact same model in Stata I get consistent results. Is there a way this can be handled? Is there an option I need to specify to cater for this?... How would I proceed?

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2021)

testdata <- tibble(
  var1 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.12),
  var2 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.82),
  var3 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.60),
  var4 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.18),
  var5 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.12),
  var6 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.05),
  var7 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.63),
  var8 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.20),
  var9 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.06),
  var10 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.40),
  var11 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.35),
  var12 = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.32),
  outcome = rbinom(1114, 1, 0.04)
) %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(), 
                ~factor(., levels = c(0, 1),
                        labels = c("No", "Yes"))))



mvariate.regress <- function(outcome, covariates, mydata) {
  form <- paste(outcome, "~",
                paste(covariates, collapse = " + "))

  model1 <- glm(as.formula(form),
                data = mydata, family = binomial)

  model1

}


ipvars <- paste0("var", 1:12)

mlogitfit <- mvariate.regress("outcome", ipvars, testdata)

summary(mlogitfit)
confint(mlogitfit)
```

var1 and var2 pvalues and CIs seem not to agree.

```
Stata Output 
        Coef.      Std. Err.    z     P>|z|      [95% Conf. Interval]
var1   .7269858    .360992     2.01   0.044     .0194544    1.434517
var2   -.6520712   .3250667   -2.01   0.045     -1.28919   -.0149521
```

Seems Stata computes CIs using a different method

Comment: Can you provide additional details about "pvalues and confidence intervals not being consistent"? They seem fine to me. Also, if you perform the same analysis with the same exact data on Stata and R, and you get different results, something is wrong. Are you using the same data, or are you using the same seed? Because the latter may imply different data on the two softwares.

Comment: I actually just exported the same data to stata

Comment: ```var1 = pvalue = 0.0440 ; CI = [-0.02442988  1.40382392]``` The CI crosses the null value yet the pvalue is significant

Comment: ```var2 = pvalue = 0.0449 ; CI = [-1.27181765  0.01143737]```

Comment: Ook, I thought this was your concerning. And what results you get from Stata?

Comment: ```var1 =  p value = 0.044   ; CI =   [.0194544    1.434517]```

Comment: ```var2 =  pvalue = 0.045   ; CI =  [-1.28919   -.0149521]```

Comment: The results in Stata are in a similar direction

Comment: This is super strange. Either you are doing something different, or one of the software has some bug. How are you computing standard errors in Stata?

Comment: Quite not sure how Stata computes the standard errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241370/discussion-between-plastic-man-and-moses).

Comment: I think this is expected, you're using different calculations to get the confidence intervals. Stata is using the standard error  (e.g. for var 1 `0.72699 - (qnorm(0.975)*0.36099)` will get the same lower bound as Stata). I believe `confint` uses profile likelihood confidence intervals for `glm`

Comment: So which one of the two would be more accurate?

Comment: I think that's a question for cross validated or some further research, but the method implemented by `confint` will not be symmetric and better reflect the true distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following suggestions from the comments, I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/why-is-there-a-difference-between-manually-calculating-a-logistic-regression-95).

The reason why R gives different confidence intervals (but same coefficients, standard errors, ecc.) is the way they are computed by `confint()`, i.e., by profiling the likelihood. The default method of Stata should be based on the Wald method, that is on normal approximation. Indeed, running `confint.default()` on R returns the same Stata's confidence intervals.

I just summarised the answer @chl's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/why-is-there-a-difference-between-manually-calculating-a-logistic-regression-95), so please consider go and upvote him.